# Procedure executes repeatedly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2019 (v15.0.2000.5) and SQL Server Management Studio 15.0.18390.0.

I have a stored procedure with a simple job: add values to the table.

```sql
CREATE DATABASE productsdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE Products 
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    ProductName NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Manufacturer NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Price MONEY NOT NULL,
    InStockAmount INT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
);

CREATE PROCEDURE AddProduct
    @name NVARCHAR(30),
    @manufacturer NVARCHAR(30),
    @price MONEY,
    @amount INT
AS
    INSERT INTO Products(ProductName, Manufacturer, Price, InStockAmount)
    VALUES (@name, @manufacturer, @price, @amount)
```

Then I execute the procedure:

```sql
EXEC AddProduct 'Galaxy C7', 'Samsung', 22000, 4
```

And weird magic happens:

```
(1 row affected)

(1 row affected)

(1 row affected)

... [32 times in total]
```

> Msg 217, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AddProduct, Line 25 [Batch Start Line 2]
> Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view
> nesting level exceeded (limit 32).

When doing `SELECT * FROM Products;`, there are really 32 copies of same product:

| id | name | manufacturer | amount | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 143 | Galaxy C7 | Samsung | 4 | 22000,00 |
| 144 | Galaxy C7 | Samsung | 5 | 22000,00 |
| 145 | Galaxy C7 | Samsung | 5 | 22000,00 |
| 146 | Galaxy C7 | Samsung | 5 | 22000,00 |
| 147 | Galaxy C7 | Samsung | 5 | 22000,00 |
| 148 | Galaxy C7 | Samsung | 5 | 22000,00 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Also, I'd noticed that amount somehow goes from 4 to 5.

Any thought what could be the issue of unintended looping?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't separate your batches for your `CREATE PROCEDURE` and `EXEC AddProduct` and so you execute the procedure within itself.

Comment: They are not coded together in the same file.
But you gave a hint.
I altered the procedure, added BEGIN and END instructions into it. And now it works fine.

Comment: It's not a coincidence that the level of nesting is 32, so that's certainly what did.

Comment: `BEGIN...END` doesn't start/end a batch, @VardoTernos . Adding them would have done nothing if you didn't separate your batches

Comment: This is a beginner’s mistake, but not a typo.  OP posted a good answer and this question should be reopened so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't separate the batches.

After coding the procedure I decided to test it by executing, but in the same batch. Which made procedure recursive (`EXEC` call was included to the procedure):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE AddProduct
    @name NVARCHAR(30),
    @manufacturer NVARCHAR(30),
    @price MONEY,
    @amount INT
AS
    INSERT INTO Products (ProductName, Manufacturer, Price, InStockAmount) 
    VALUES (@name, @manufacturer, @price, @amount);

-- Here I didn't separate the batches, which was a mistake

EXEC AddProduct 'Galaxy C7', 'Samsung', 22000, 4;
```

Adding a `GO` statement where comment is fixed the issue.

Comment: Being nit-picky: `GO` **isn't** a (T-SQL) **statement** - it's a batch separator used by SSMS (and some other MS tools)

Comment: It's also just the default and can be changed in the settings; the fun you can have by changing it to "select" on your colleagues...